# Lat Long to Minutes and Seconds?

Tags: latitude-longitude, degrees, seconds

Google Maps gives me the Lat and Long of a location in decimal notation like this:

38.203655,-76.113281

How do I convert those to Coords (Degrees, Minutes , Seconds)

Comment: [Decimal Degrees to Degrees Minutes Seconds](http://www.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html)

Comment: Co-ordinate systems and conversions are explained here, with pseudocode: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion"> Co-ordinate conversion (from Wikipedia)</a>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

38.203655 is a decimal value of degrees. There are 60 minutes is a degree and 60 seconds in a minute (1degree == 60min == 3600s).

So take the fractional part of the value, i.e. 0.203655, and multiply it with 60 to get minutes, i.e. 12.2193, which is 12 minutes, and then repeat for the fractional part of minutes, i.e. 0.2193 = 13.158000 seconds.

Example in python:

```
def deg_to_dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]

print deg_to_dms(38.203655)
print deg_to_dms(-76.113281)
```

Comment: Good solution.  Minor note: typically for DMS format, it is not signed but rather uses the cardinal direction (ie, not -76 12 34.567 but W76 12 34.567).

Answer (score 0):

In case you need other geo-related functionality in JavaScript, you may use the following library

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

it provides the following functionality:

- DMS from/to decimal latitude/longitude conversions
- Distance calculations
- Bearing calculation
- Intersection point calcualtion

Answer (score 0):

Python library that does the trick:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LatLon/1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you with the solution :

```
def deg_min_sec(self,degrees=0.0):
        if type(degrees) != 'float':
            try:
                degrees = float(degrees)
            except:
                print '\nERROR: Could not convert %s to float.' % (type(degrees))
                return 0
        minutes = degrees % 1.0 * 60
        seconds = minutes % 1.0 * 60

        return (degrees, minutes, seconds)
```