# Convert Latitude/Longitude to decimal degree value

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

I have lat/long value in this format

```
5,141,456,024   -231,146,115
```

I want to convert these values in to decimal degree like

```
51.3758010864258 -2.35989999771118
```

I have 25K records which I want to convert into decimal degree

Thanks

Comment: What is the conversion function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in function in c#, you should do it by hand (just coding the proper formula)

Anyway, there are quite a lot of examples on GoogleNet

e.g. [link](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/21711-Longitude-or-Latitude-Convert-Degrees-Minute.aspx)

Comment: And quite a few answers on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056750/lat-long-to-minutes-and-seconds/2056771#2056771

Answer (score -12):

Step 1: Find out what the first set of Coordinates represent

Step 2: Remember basic algebra from middle school

Step 3: Devise a method to convert them to the WGS84 scheme

Step 4: Implement ...

Seriously, do your own homework.

Comment: Not in the slightest bit helpful, algebra??

Comment: Answers like this will result in discouraging people from asking questions. Which is the whole purpose of this site