# How to show mouse position of latituds and logituds to MGRS in Openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have integrated openlayers3 in my project and it shows mouse position into latitudes and longitudes format.
What I want is to show mouse position in MGRS format as well.
How to do that please help.
[Demo Here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mouse-position.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lat Long to Minutes and Seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056750/lat-long-to-minutes-and-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

The MousePosition control takes an optional coordinateFormat function, that takes the coordinate as an argument and returns a formatted string.

You could write your own or use a built in. I'm not sure what you mean by "GPS format", but assuming that it is the latitude and longitude in hours, minutes and seconds as produce by `ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS`.

```
var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
  coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS,
  projection: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```

Comment: I mean GPS Coordinate

Comment: What's your definition of GPS Coordinate?

Comment: GPS, which stands for Global Positioning System, is a radio navigation system that allows land, sea, and airborne users to determine their exact location, velocity, and time 24 hours a day, in all weather conditions, anywhere in the world.

Comment: We all know what GPS is. I'm asking what format you want the coordinates in, since there is no standardized format known as "GPS format" or "GPS coordinates". An example output or link to someone doing it "right" might help.

Comment: Oh God my Mistak, MGRS not GPS.